# I can't transfer property in child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to pass prop(string array) in my child component and I get this: "Cannot destructure property 'taskList' of 'this.state' as it is null." (Used destructurization). What am I doing wrong?

```
type AppStates = {
  taskList: string[],
  inputValue: string,
}

class App extends Component<{}, AppStates> {
  handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.taskList.push(this.state.inputValue);

    this.setState({inputValue: ""});
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const {taskList, inputValue} = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div className='toDo-list'>
        <h1 className='toDo-list__header'>ToDo List</h1>
        <form className='toDo-list__form'>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Enter task' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add task</button>
        </form>
        
        <TaskList taskList={taskList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are learning, please create function components as React recommends https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as the comment says, the state is null initially which you cannot destructure. You should set the default state to be

```
{
    taskList: [],
    inputValue: ""
}
```